# Querying efficiently

Tags: php, mysql, sql, query-performance

I have two tables: Exam (ExamID, Date, Modality) and CT(ctdivol, ExamID(FK)) with the attributes in brackets.

**Note**: CT table has about 100 000 entries.

I want to calculate the average of ctdivol in a specific interval of dates.

I have this code that works but is too slow:

```
function get_CTDIvolAVG($min, $max) {

$values = 0;
$number = 0;

$query = "SELECT  (unix_timestamp(date)*1000), examID
    from  exam use index(dates)
    where  modality = 'CT'
      AND  (unix_timestamp(date)*1000) between '" . $min . "' AND '" . $max . "';";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());

while($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

    $avg = "SELECT  SUM(ctdivol_mGy), count(ctdivol_mGy)
    from  ct use index(ctd)
    where  examID ='" . $line["examID"] ."'
      AND  ctdivol_mGy>0;";
    $result1 = mysql_query($avg) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
    while ($ct = mysql_fetch_array($result1, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

        $values = $values + floatval($ct["SUM(ctdivol_mGy)"]);
        $number = $number + floatval($ct["count(ctdivol_mGy)"]);

    }
}
if ($number!=0) {
    echo $values/$number;

}

}
```

How can I make it faster?

Comment: This is better asked at our member site specifically for [dba experts](http://dba.stackexchange.com/), ooh and I didn't downvote.

Comment: do you have some sample date for http://sqlfiddle.com/ and a the expected result

Comment: Avoid SQL inside loop which slow down; Use SQL to do aggregation instead of PHP

Comment: please stop using deprecated mysql_ functions and start using pdo or mysqli instead.

Answer (score 3):

Use `EXPLAIN` to see the query execution plan.

For that first query, MySQL can't make effective use of a index range scan operation. That expression in the `WHERE` clause has to be evaluated for *every* row in the table. We get better performance when we do the comparison to a *bare* column. Do the manipulation on the literal side... get those values converted to the datatype of the column you're comparing to.

```
WHERE e.date BETWEEN expr1 AND expr2
```

For `expr1`, you need an expression that converts your `$min` value into a datetime. Just be careful of timezone conversions. I think this might do what you need for expr1:

```
 FROM_UNIXTIME( $min /1000)
```

Something like:

```
WHERE e.date BETWEEN FROM_UNIXTIME( $min /1000) AND FROM_UNIXTIME( $max /1000)
```

Then we should see MySQL able to make effective use of an index with leading column of date. The EXPLAIN output should show `range` for the access type.

If the number of columns being returned is a small subset, consider a *covering index*. Then the EXPLAIN will show "Using index", which means the query can be satisfied entirely from the index, with no lookups to pages in the underlying table.

---

Secondly, avoid running queries multiple times in a loop. It is usually more efficient to run a single query that returns a single resultset, because of the overhead of sending the SQL to the database, that database parsing the SQL text, for valid syntax (keywords in the right places), valid semantics (identifiers reference valid objects), considering possible access paths and determining which is lowest cost, then executing the query plan, obtaining metadata locks, generating the resultset, returning that to the client, and then cleaning up. It's not noticeable for a single statement, but when you start running a lot of statements in a tight loop, it starts to add up. Couple that with an inefficient  query, and it starts to get really noticeable.

---

IF `examID` column in `exam` is unique and not null (or its the PRIMARY KEY of `exam`, then it looks like you could use a single query, like this:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(e.date)*1000 AS `date_ts`
     , e.examID                    AS `examID`
     , SUM(ct.ctdivol_mGy)         AS `SUM(ctdivol_mGy)`
     , COUNT(ct.ctdivol_mGy)       AS `count(ctdivol_mGy)`
  FROM exam e
  LEFT
  JOIN ct
    ON ct.examid = e.examID
   AND ct.ctdivol_mGy > 0
 WHERE e.modality = 'CT'
   AND e.date >= FROM_UNIXTIME(  $min  /1000)
   AND e.date <= FROM_UNIXTIME(  $max  /1000)
 GROUP
    BY e.modality
     , e.date
     , e.examID
 ORDER
    BY e.modality
     , e.date
     , e.examID
```

For best performance of that, you'd want covering indexes:

```
  ... ON exam (modality, date, examID)
  ... ON ct (examID, ctdivol_mGy)
```

We'd want to see the `EXPLAIN` output; we'd expect that MySQL could make use of the index on exam to do the GROUP BY (and avoiding a "Using filesort" operation), and also make use of a `ref` operation on the index to `ct`.

To reiterate... that query requires that `examID` be the PRIMARY KEY of the `exam` table (or at least be guaranteed to be unique and non-null). Otherwise, the result from that can be different than the original code. Absent that gurantee, we could use either an inline view, or subqueries in the `SELECT` list. But in terms of performance, we don't want to go there without good reason to.

That's just some general ideas, not a hard and fast "this will be faster".

Comment: Thanks for your explanation @spencer7593 . It worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

You can write a join on the first table to a subquery table by exam_id:

```
$query = "SELECT (unix_timestamp(date)*1000) as time_calculation, ed.examID, inner_ct.inner_sum, inner_ct.inner_count "
" FROM exam ed,"
. " ( SELECT SUM(ctdivol_mGy) as inner_sum, count(ctdivol_mGy) as inner_count, examID"
. "   FROM ct"
. "   WHERE  ctdivol_mGy>0 ) inner_ct"
. " WHERE ed.modality = 'CT' AND time_calculation between"
. " '$min' and '$max'"
. " AND ed.examId = inner_ct.examID";
```

The `( SELECT . . .) inner_ct` creates an in memory table you can join from. Useful if you're selecting composed data (sums in your case) across a join.

Conversely, you can use the following syntax:

```
$query = "SELECT (unix_timestamp(date)*1000) as time_calculation, ed.examID, inner_ct.inner_sum, inner_ct.inner_count "
" FROM exam ed,"
. " LEFT JOIN ( SELECT SUM(ctdivol_mGy) as inner_sum, count(ctdivol_mGy) as inner_count, examID"
. "   FROM ct"
. "   WHERE  ctdivol_mGy>0 ) inner_ct"
. " ON ed.examID = inner_ct.examID"
. " WHERE ed.modality = 'CT' AND time_calculation between"
. " '$min' and '$max'";
```

Comment: its recommend to use the new join syntax. its also better to read / understand

Comment: Not sure I follow. I personally feel that join aliases are more legible when writing subquery tables. But, this is in my opinion, strictly personal preference.

Comment: and do not calculate in a WHERE Clause with the field content like this **(unix_timestamp(date)*1000) = **  better is do do the calculations on the other site ** min/1000** . when you calculate with the field MySQL must read all row and calculate to see if the WHERE is true

Comment: sorry, i didn´t mean the derived table with the alias. SELECT * from tab1 LEFT JOIN (SELECT ......) AS  inner_ct is only better to read an recommend from MySQL

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided sample data in the question so we resort to assumptions in an attempt to answer. If there is only one `exam` row for many rows in `ct` - but an exam row can exist that has no ct rows at all - then this single query should provide the results required.

```
SELECT
      exam.examID
    , (unix_timestamp(exam.date) * 1000
    , SUM(ct.ctdivol_mGy)
    , COUNT(ct.ctdivol_mGy)
FROM exam
LEFT OUTER JOIN ct on exam.examID = ct.examID AND ct.ctdivol_mGy > 0
WHERE exam.modality = 'CT'
      AND exam.date >= @min AND exam.date < @max
GROUP BY
      exam.examID
    , (unix_timestamp(exam.date) * 1000)
      ;
```

Note I am not attempting the PHP code, just concentrating on the SQL. I have used `@min` and `@max` to indicate the 2 dates required in the where clause. These should be of the same data type as the column `exam.date` so do those calculations in PHP before adding into the query string.

---

> I want to calculate the average of ctdivol in a specific interval of
>   dates.

If you are trying to return a single figure, then this should help:

```
SELECT
      AVG(ct.ctdivol_mGy)
FROM exam
INNER JOIN ct on exam.examID = ct.examID AND ct.ctdivol_mGy > 0
WHERE exam.modality = 'CT'
      AND exam.date >= @min AND exam.date < @max
      ;
```

Note for this variant we probably don't need a left join (but again due to a lack of sample data and expected result that is an assumption).

Comment: Just another question @Used_By_Already  , is there any way to calculate de 90th percentile instead of the average?

Comment: Unable to add much now. But read this. http://rpbouman.blogspot.com.au/2008/07/calculating-nth-percentile-in-mysql.html?m=1

Comment: for 90th percentile also read http://rpbouman.blogspot.com.au/2008/07/calculating-percentiles-with-mysql.html this one is more efficient as it does not rely on group_concat, If you are unable to get it to work open a new question - but please include "sample data" and "expected result" for sql questions